# WHCS Price via API with dynamic array

Tags: php, api, whmcs

I want to know how to get WHMCS Price via WHMCS API.

I have created a little script to get price via API which is working fine but when I update the script on my external WHMCS pages it is taking a lot more time to update the function on each page my simple question is to get price via API without defining the first array see example below.

```
Array
(
    [result] => success
    [totalresults] => xxx
    [products] => Array
        (
            [product] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array // how can I call it dynamically
                        (
                            [pid] => 1
                            [gid] => 1
                            [type] => hostingaccount
                            [name] => Plan Name
                            [description] => Plan Description
                            [module] => cpanel
                            [paytype] => recurring
                            [pricing] => Array
                                (
                                    [USD] => Array
                                        (
                                            [prefix] => $
                                            [suffix] => USD
                                            [msetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [qsetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [ssetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [asetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [bsetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [tsetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [monthly] => 0.14
                                            [quarterly] => 0.39
                                            [semiannually] => 0.73
                                            [annually] => 1.32
                                            [biennially] => 2.39
                                            [triennially] => 3.20
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I just want to get price after I define [pid] and then I will create a function like

`GetPrice($pid, $billingcycle); // to get produce price according to tenure`

**My Script:**

```
$identifier = "IDENTIFIER";
$secret = "SECRET";
$APIURL = "mydomain/whmcs_directory/includes/api.php"; // it is with HTTPS

$postfields = array(
    'username' => $identifier,
    'password' => $secret,
    'action' => 'GetProducts',
    'responsetype' => 'json',
);

// Call the API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $APIURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

// Decode response
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);
```

and then I want to use function to get price according product id & tenure as defined earlier but complete function looks like this.

```
function GetPrice($pid, $billingcycle){

    // $pid will be product ID
    // $billingcycle will be 1,3,6,12,24,36 accordingly.

    /**
     * It would be great if I could just remove "["products"]["product"]" 
     * But I understand to call API I have define them so it's Okay.
     */

    $monthly        =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][$pid]["pricing"]["USD"]["monthly"];
    $quarterly      =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][$pid]["pricing"]["USD"]["quarterly"];
    $semiannually   =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][$pid]["pricing"]["USD"]["semiannually"];
    $annually       =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][$pid]["pricing"]["USD"]["annually"];
    $biennially     =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][$pid]["pricing"]["USD"]["biennially"];
    $triennially    =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][$pid]["pricing"]["USD"]["triennially"];

    if( $billingcycle == "1"  ){
        echo $monthly;
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "3"  ){
        echo $quarterly;
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "6"  ){
        echo $semiannually;
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "12"  ){
        echo $annually;
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "24"  ){
        echo $biennially;
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "36"  ){
        echo $triennially;
    }
}
```

I got help from [WHMCS API Reference](http://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/getproducts/)

*This has done with php, please improve my code if require.*

Comment: You can save the pid related array into a new variable, like this:
$productDetails = $jsonData["products"]["product"][$pid];
then:
$monthly = $productDetails["pricing"]["USD"]["monthly"];

Comment: @wesamlyThank for spending time to review the main reason is to ask question here to get rid of first array under product let me update my code for better understanding

Comment: Code has just updated please have a look

Comment: If you're getting one product, you can set pid parameter for the API postfields. Or you build you're own array after retrieving all products, loop through them and assign to new array with pid as key,e.g: foreach( jsonData[products][product] as item) { newArr[item[pid]]=item }

Comment: @wesamly Thank you for the idea I didn't thought that way let me update my answer so other can get advantage from this.

Comment: you're welcome. please add it as answer. good luck.

Comment: @wesamly I have voted your answer also posted my complete function and hope it won't need improvement, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved this with the following code which work dynamically and works with product id.

**PHP Function**

```
function GetPrice($product_id, $billingcycle){

    $identifier = "WHMCS_IDENTIFIER";
    $secret = "WHMCS_SECRET";
    $APIURL = "YOURDOMAIN.com/WHMCS_DIRECTORY/includes/api.php"; // use HTTPS

    $postfields = array(
        'username'      =>  $identifier,
        'password'      =>  $secret,
        'action'        =>  'GetProducts',
        'pid'           =>  $product_id, // Product id
        'responsetype'  =>  'json',
    );

    // Call the API
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $APIURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); // SET to 0 for non SSL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        //die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));
        die("Out of Stock");
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    // Decode response
    $jsonData = json_decode($response, true);

    $monthly        =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][0]["pricing"]["USD"]["monthly"];
    $quarterly      =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][0]["pricing"]["USD"]["quarterly"];
    $semiannually   =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][0]["pricing"]["USD"]["semiannually"];
    $annually       =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][0]["pricing"]["USD"]["annually"];
    $biennially     =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][0]["pricing"]["USD"]["biennially"];
    $triennially    =   $jsonData["products"]["product"][0]["pricing"]["USD"]["triennially"];

    if( $billingcycle == "1"  ){
        echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $monthly), 2 );
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "3"  ){
        echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $quarterly) / 3, 2 );
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "6"  ){
        echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $semiannually) / 6, 2 );
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "12"  ){
        echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $annually) / 12, 2 );
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "24"  ){
        echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $biennially) / 24, 2 );
    }

    if( $billingcycle == "36"  ){
        echo round( str_replace('.00', '', $triennially) / 36, 2 );
    }
}
```

**Using Function**

```
echo GetPrice( 1 , 1 );
```

**Output**

```
1.99
```